# How to start lsp-mode connections lazily after desktop is restored?

Tags: lsp-mode, desktop, lsp

I have configured lsp-mode as follows:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :straight t
  :init (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook ((python-mode . lsp))
  :commands lsp)
```

I am also using desktop-save-mode to restore my editing state upon restart. When I have several projects open and quit Emacs, the restart takes a long time as it starts each lsp server. Is there a way to start each server only when I run an lsp-related command in the buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :straight t
  :init (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook (python-mode . lsp-deferred))
```

The doc for `lsp-deferred`:

```
Signature
(lsp-deferred)

Documentation
Entry point that defers server startup until buffer is visible.

lsp-deferred will wait until the buffer is visible before invoking lsp.
This avoids overloading the server with many files when starting Emacs.
```

Edit: I've encountered some issues with this as described by scry, if the above doesn't work, try his workaround (I've opened a PR here: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/pull/3975).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, since when `lsp-mode` is already listed as a minor mode in the saved buffers, `desktop-read` will activate it before `lsp-deferred` runs.

Instead, I'm using this:

```lisp
(defun my-lsp-deferred-on (_)
  (lsp-deferred))
(setq desktop-minor-mode-table
   '((lsp-mode my-lsp-deferred) 
     ...))
```

`desktop-minor-mode-table` tells Desktop how to restore the minor mode:

```
Table mapping minor mode variables to minor mode functions.
Each entry has the form (NAME RESTORE-FUNCTION).
NAME is the name of the buffer-local variable indicating that the minor
mode is active.  RESTORE-FUNCTION is the function to activate the minor mode.
```

Note that the function is called with one argument like a minor-mode function, but `lsp-deferred` takes none, hence the placeholder; also, it has to be mapped by its name, so we can't just use a lambda.

Comment: I've encountered similar issues, I opened a PR a while ago: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/pull/3975, the approach I think is similar to your snippet.  I'll edit my answer.